# Navdata altitude value altd is always 0 in ardrone navigation data

Tags: ros, ardrone

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to read the altitude of the drone using the navdata, but the height is always 0. Could someone help out in this regard. The other values such as acceleration etc. are fine. I am printing out the data on the terminal using rostopic echo, so there shouldn't be an error with data types either. Please help

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/106026/navdata-altitude-value-altd-is-always-0-in-ardrone-navigation-data/) by [venturi](https://answers.ros.org/users/9341/venturi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2013-11-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Sorry about that, i figured it out. Just had to read the documentation. Apparently the data is sent only when the drone is flying.

---

Originally posted by [venturi](https://answers.ros.org/users/9341/venturi/) with karma: 16 on 2013-11-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0